# Referencing columns in .SDcols using for loop

Tags: r, data.table, nested-for-loop

So what I'm trying to achieve is this : Say I have a data table dt having (say) 4 columns. I want to get unique length of every combination of 2 columns.

```
DT <- data.table(a = 1:10, b = c(1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5), c = letters[1:10], d = c(3,3,5,2,4,2,5,1,1,5))

> DT
    a b c d
1:  1 1 a 3
2:  2 1 b 3
3:  3 1 c 5
4:  4 2 d 2
5:  5 2 e 4
6:  6 3 f 2
7:  7 4 g 5
8:  8 4 h 1
9:  9 5 i 1
10: 10 5 j 5
```

I tried the following code :

```
cols <- colnames(DT)
for(i in 1:(length(cols)-1)) {
for (j in i+1:length(cols)) {
    print(unique(DT[,.SD, .SDcols = c(cols[i],cols[j])]))
     }   
   }
```

Here, basically 'i' goes from first column to second last whereas 'j' is the combining column with 'i'. So the combinations I get are : ab, ac, ad, bc, bd, cd.

But it gives me the following error

> Error in `[.data.table`(DT, , .SD, .SDcols = c(cols[i], cols[j])) :
> .SDcols missing at the following indices: [2]

If someone can explain why this is and a way around it, I'll be really grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to [operators precedence](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Syntax.html), `:` is evaluated before `+`:

```
1+1:length(cols)
[1] 2 3 4 5
> (1+1):length(cols)
[1] 2 3 4
```

Correct loop is :

```
for(i in 1:(length(cols)-1)) {
  for (j in (i+1):length(cols)) {
    print(unique(DT[,.SD, .SDcols = c(cols[i],cols[j])]))
  }   
}
```